# Eclipse showing 'Object' instead of correct type for var

Tags: java, eclipse, var

I am new to the `var` keyword, and I am trying to understand something in Eclipse.

The code I have is:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> savedConfirmations = USERS.fetchStaffAccessConfirmed(managerId, dates)
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, (o) -> o.getValue().keySet()));
```

When I change the type from `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>` to `var` Eclipse tells me it is an `Object` when I hover over it.

[image: Correct type]

[image: Incorrect type]

However I am able to use the variable as if it is a `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>` in both ways without error.

Eg:

```
savedConfirmations.get(1);
```

It appears to only effect `Collectors.toMap`, as if I collect to a List the hover shows its correct type.

Is there something I am misunderstanding about `var`?

---

Edit

Here is a small class which replicates the issue:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
    public int test() {
        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> fakeConfirmations = new HashMap<>();

        // Change this line to 'var'
        Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> confirmations = fakeConfirmations
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                                          (o) -> o.getValue().keySet()));

        return confirmations.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're able to use it as a Map, it's probably an Eclipse glitch

Comment: Which release of Eclipse is this, and what is your project's compiler compliance set to?

Comment: @nitind Sorry, I definitely should have included that. Eclipse 4.21.0 (20210910-1417), JDK Compliance 11 (Generated class & Source compatibility are also both 11)

Comment: I also see this sometimes, it just seems to be the hover information - you are not misunderstanding var this is definitely an Eclipse issue.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21). Please show a minimal reproducible example that can be compiled of its own.

Comment: @howlger Sure thing, I have added an edit with a small self-contained example

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'm not able to reproduce this with the given example in Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21) on Windows 10. Do you have the Java 17 support plugin or other additional plugins installed? Do you get this always or only the first time when hovering?

Comment: @howlger I do not believe I have the Java 17 support plugin. It is a vanilla install of Eclipse under Debian 11 and the project was migrated from an older version of Eclipse. It happens every time I hover over that particular variable.

Comment: @threenplusone What happens if you delete all in the line before `fakeConfirmations` , hit Ctrl+1 and choose _Assign statement to new local variable_?

Comment: @howlger When I do that it generates the correct type : Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>

Comment: @threenplusone That's strange. Which Java version do you use in your project?

Comment: @howlger I'm using Java 11 for the project, and I have installed "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.12+7-post-Debian-2, mixed mode, sharing)"

Comment: @threenplusone Thx. And in the _Javadoc_ view? When I select `var`, in the _Javadoc_ view I get also `java.util.Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>` (with both, Java 11 and 16). Is the hover and _Javadoc_ view different for you?

Comment: @howlger When I hover of the 'var' keyword it shows me the correct Javadoc `java.util.Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>`

Comment: I have just noticed something further, it is only an `Object` if my keyMapper is `Entry::getKey`. If I change it to `(o) -> o.getKey()` the hover shows correctly